# S5 automatic notifications

Tags: wi-fi, notifications

My S5 device is automatically connecting to the wifi in range, receiving notifications (such as what's up, facebook etc...) then turning wifi off.
Wifi timer is always disabled.
Any solution please?

Comment: This is not normal behavior, so it is probably related to this Wifi Timer app of yours. Try uninstalling the app and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, but what's the application name as I couldn't find it through application manager.

Answer (score 0):

I'm giving the method to disable this in Xperia phones. Maybe Samsung follow the same. Tap on Settings\Wifi\Advanced settings\Scanning always available. Disable Scanning always available.

Comment: I don't think that's happening here, as scanning doesn't connect to a Wi-Fi network, it only scans for available networks, as the name suggests.

Comment: Thanks Mani, but this won't solve the problem. I tried all possible solutions in Advanced Wifi settings without any success.

Comment: @StephanHanna - Okay. Have you tried power saving mode?

Comment: Power saving mode has nothing to do with the wifi auto connection. However, I usually use this feature and the problem still unresolved.

Comment: Okay. I'll come back with some solution if possible.